# How could a deprecation warning be triggered through a package?

Tags: python

In a unittest I am newly getting

```
werkzeug/local.py:347: DeprecationWarning: json is deprecated.  Use get_json() instead.
```

I trace this back to the relevant file `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py`. The offending line is the last in the following method.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == '__members__':
        return dir(self._get_current_object())
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)  # Line 347
```

The move to `request.get_json()` from `request.json` seems to be quite old (2013?), and a quick recursive grep in Werkzeug's files shows that `request.json` is not used. 
The offending code, using `request.json` rather than `request.get_json()`, appears to be my own. Both Werkzeug and Flask in my venv are 0.12.2.

How could a deprecation warning be triggered through a package, and without `pytest` even pointing to the line that actually uses the deprecated interface?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the package is triggering the DeprecationWarning, per se. [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning) is looking at the code and warning you to the fact that the code is deprecated, which may or may not be under your control.

> By default pytest will display DeprecationWarning and
>   PendingDeprecationWarning warnings from user code and third-party
>   libraries, as recommended by PEP-0565. This helps users keep their
>   code modern and avoid breakages when deprecated warnings are
>   effectively removed.
>
> Sometimes it is useful to hide some specific deprecation warnings that
>   happen in code that you have no control over (such as third-party
>   libraries), in which case you might use the warning filters options
>   (ini or marks) to ignore those warnings.

As for how the deprecation warning is triggered, and where it should attribute it to, it looks like [PEP 565](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0565/) has something to say on that:

> In Python 2.7 and Python 3.2, the default warning filters were updated
>   to hide DeprecationWarning by default, such that deprecation warnings
>   in development tools that were themselves written in Python (e.g.
>   linters, static analysers, test runners, code generators), as well as
>   any other applications that merely happened to be written in Python,
>   wouldn't be visible to their users unless those users explicitly opted
>   in to seeing them.
>
> However, this change has had the unfortunate side effect of making
>   DeprecationWarning markedly less effective at its primary intended
>   purpose: providing advance notice of breaking changes in APIs (whether
>   in CPython, the standard library, or in third party libraries) to
>   users of those APIs.
>
> To improve this situation, this PEP proposes a single adjustment to
>   the default warnings filter: displaying deprecation warnings
>   attributed to the main module by default.

As for where your json deprecation warning is coming from, it seems odd that pytest is pointing you to Werzkug and it is not used in there at all. Perhaps this is due to some of the limitations above?